# Convert nodejs server to ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

**I have my nodejs server like this:**

```
const app  = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io   = require('socket.io')(http);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Routes ===============================================
require('./routes.js')(app);

// Socket.io ============================================
require('./socket.js')(io);

// Launch ===============================================
http.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('The magic happens on port '+port);
});
```

**I would like to chage it to ES6 syntax but I am not sure how to I am trying something like this:**

```
import express  = 'express';
import http = 'http';
import io = 'socket.io';
import routes './routes';
import sockets './sockets';

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Routes ===============================================
routes(express);

// Socket.io ============================================
sockets(io);

// Launch ===============================================
http.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('The magic happens on port '+port);
});
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Update your node.js to the latest version?

Comment: import them, then call them with said parameters. where's the confusion? you've already proven you know how given your example with `import express`.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @jfriend00 How to convert that code to a ES6 syntax?

Comment: We don't write your code for you.  You need to ask a more specific question.  You obviously already know how to do `import express from 'express';` and `let app = express();`.  What part don't you know?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not sure how to import http, socket.io and then pass app and http as parameters, and what would be the ES6 equivalent of require('./socket.js')(io);

Comment: Next time, please state exactly what you do and don't know in your question so we know exactly what you're asking about.  We didn't know why you thought the `http` example was any different than the express example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import socketIo from 'socket.io';

import routes from './routes';
import sockets from './sockets';

const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

app.use(routes);
const mySockets = sockets(io);
```

Comment: what about require('./routes.js')(app);
require('./socket.js')(io);

Comment: for routes, import routes from ./'routes';  app.use(routes). Not sure what you do you mean about socket.js. Can you please give a little more explanation?

Comment: I just have a module.exports of all my socket.io in another js file

Comment: I would be import sockets from './sockets'; const mySockets = sockets(io);

Comment: 'socket.io' package isn't a client. naming it `ioClient` is kinda misleading

Comment: @Tibebes.M make sense. I am terrible at naming and it was a prototype where I didn't think about the var naming. I have changed it now.